# ExtJs 4:how to let the validator triggered when a field lose focus?

Tags: extjs

I want to add a customized validator to a field,I do it like this:

```
Ext.apply( Ext.form.field.VTypes,{
sampleSetExist: function(val, field) {
    alert('val='+val);
}
});
```

I find that the validator will be triggered once my key up,is there any way to let the validator triggered when the field lose focus?
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[blur](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-event-blur)** event, which get triggered when the field lose Focus

To enable a button to be only active when the form is valid use

```
formBind: true, //only enabled once the form is valid
disabled: true,
```

Comment: thank you,I know the blur event,but I was use a form panel,and the submit is bind to the form,just when all validators are success,the submit button will be enable,this is very convenient.if I use blur enent,I have to check if the submit button should be enable myself.

Comment: @liupeng Ok, what about a formbound button? See my edit. Ops, I see you are using this still. Sorry, then I can't follow you? Where is your problem? Lose focus is blur, run the sustom validate function and you should be fine I guess?

Comment: now my submit button is bind to the form,this work well,but i just want to add a customized validator to a field,by default,the validator will be triggered once I press a key,I do not want this,I want to trigger the validator when the field lose focus.If I can know a field has focus or not?

Comment: @liupeng Well [validateOnBlur](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-validateOnBlur) is true by default same as [validateOnChange](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-validateOnChange) which you likely will change to false. Your problem is now that button will stay inactive cause the last field will still keep the focus?

Comment: thank you very much,I watch the api,and find the default value of validateOnBlur is true,but my field will trigger the validator when the content change,which is very strange.you let me notice that there are configuration item：validateOnBlur and validateOnChange,when i use them,the problem get solved,thank you!

Comment: @liupeng You're welcome. So You consider choosing this as answer ;)